# Organize Videos / Pics made with Camera?

Tags: 8.1, video, pictures, nokia-lumia-930

I just got a Nokia Lumia (W8.1) and try to get familiar with it. I want to use the phone to make pics/videos. To make the work with those pics/videos more easy afterwards, I'd like to have the possibility to e.g. rename the video/pic, add tags to it and display videos/pics by tag. I did not thought this would be a problem, but I am unable to find an app that does this and there (seems to be) no way to do this with the standard Nokia Camera App.

Does anybody has a tip for this?

Ciao,
Frank

Comment: As far as I know there are no apps that can do it. But the Windows phone gallery organize your pics and videos by date. Maybe you should organize them in folders, using the Files app or Aerize explorer. Also, if you sinc your pics with one drive, maybe you can set tags to your photos via the one drive app.

Comment: I have looked for apps in the past to do regular tagging and face tagging.  I have been surprised that I cannot find any.

Comment: Well, tagging is not actually rocket science, but obviously not possible on Windows Phone. Actually, the whole phone handling (e.g. I have recorded our rehearsal room sessions and just tried to get the files down on my laptop) is a bit, well ... weird. Same with documents and stuff. But at least the microphone is surprisingly good :)

I gave Aerize explorer a shot for managing the videos and pics. Still a bit clumsy but better than nothing, for sure! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

For similar needs, I use the [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl) App.

I use it to create folders (i.e. *albums*) inside the default Pictures folder and then I move photos inside them, in this way, when I open the Photos App, I can see my pics organized in different *albums*.

With Files, you can also rename your pictures. Anyway, as far as I know, there is no way to organize pictures by tags in Windows Phone.